# auto calculate 90 days from start date

Tags: excel, formula, autofill

I have found lots of instructions on how to do this and I do have it working BUT...

the problem is that when i drag the fill handle to copy multiple cells with the correct formula, it puts in a 00 date, seems like a place holder because I can then type in a date in any of those cells and it calculates and display's the correct date.

How do I get Excel to NOT show these placeholder dates?

Formula placeholder dates

[image]

thank you,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **`IF`** the start date is blank and return values accordingly

---

```
=IF(B2="","-",B2+90)
```